# Read binary data using ifstream

Tags: c, fstream

Probably, I don't know something about ifstream. I have binary file : 0604 0204 0a02.

```
std::ifstream input(input_filename, std::ios::binary);
unsigned char cmd;
unsigned char type;
while (!input.eof()) {
    input >> cmd;
    input >> type;
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(cmd) << " " << (int)type << "\n";
}
```

And result of this code:

```
6 4
2 4
2 0
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: What did you want instead? This is a very underspecified question. We cannot work out what you wanted, from code that by your own admission _does not do that thing_...

Comment: 0a is 10, these code out 0a as 2

Comment: This is obviously not your real code as you only perform input and output twice. Present an actual [mcve] not some made-up thing.

Comment: Did you forget to [add error checking](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d31ab2f6efb3efb)?

Comment: [`while !eof` is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/4386278)

Comment: Sorry, I've fixed it

Comment: It didn't help me.

Comment: You should heed it regardless as it _will_ help you

Comment: Doesn't look like C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`operator >>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stream/operator_gtgt2) is skipping white space. You need to call

```
while(input.read(&cmd, 1) && input.read(&type, 1)) {}
```

or

```
while(input >> std::noskipws >> cmd >> std::noskipws >> type) {}
```

Also please note the changed error checking (just casting the stream to bool).

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems here.

1. `0x0A` is an ASCII newline, and you're using formatted extraction. That's why your `10` is "skipped" and the `2` extracted instead.

   Use `.get()`, not `>>`
2. You're using `.eof()`, which doesn't check for extraction errors, and checks only *after* you extract, so you're getting "extra" bad data past the end of your actual read (the `0` is nonsense). [Don't use `while (!stream.eof())` in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/4386278) (usually).

Fixed code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream input(input_filename, std::ios::binary);
    while (true)
    {
        const unsigned char cmd = input.get();
        const unsigned char type = input.get();

        if (!input)
            break;

        std::cout << static_cast<int>(cmd) << " " << (int)type << "\n";
    }
}

/*
g++ -std=c++17 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
6 4
2 4
10 2
*/
```

#### [live demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77172d7de9be960c)